# Proper way of validating if I'm on the right screen in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin and I want to check if i'm on the right screen and I have this approach to it.

```
class Tome_Places
{
    function __construct( $loader )
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;

        $this->define_admin_hooks();
    }

    private function define_admin_hooks()   
    {
        $this->loader->add_action('in_admin_header', $this, 'current_screen');
    }


    function start_wrapper() {
            global $pagenow, $post_type;

            if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' && $post_type == 'tome_place' )
                echo '<div class="chapter-wrapper">';
    }


    function end_wrapper() {
            global $pagenow, $post_type;

            if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' && $post_type == 'tome_place' )
                echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

is there any better approach instead of asking in each function `if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' && $post_type == 'tome_place'` ?

thank you

Comment: You could pop the query inside a private function and call that from within the other functions. I am assuming if you made the global values private variables within your class then they might be saved in the first state they are stored and not updated if the page changes etc... (if that makes sense).

Comment: thanks for the advice, will think about that.